# c# unbound datagrid verify sum value of each columns equals to 100 or empty

Tags: c#

I am a beginner for C# code. In fact, my purpose is to let the users fill out data for each cell of the unbound grid, for each column, the sum value should be either 100 or empty. (suppose the sum value exceeds 100, the color of related columns frames should turns out to be red). I tried to write the code as follows using cellvaluechanged event but it only works when the users fill the cells row by row. if the users fill the cells by columns or by random cell, it's not working. I wanted to make sure that regardless the preference of users'habit, by row or by column, or random order, the validation of each column is not impacted. Could anyone help on this issue? thank you very much in advance.

void UnboundGridDesign1_CellValueChanged(object sender, UnboundGridValueChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            //throw new NotImplementedException();

```
        int i, j = 0;
        double[,] arr = new double[10, 10];
        double[] sumVals = new double[10];

        for (i = 2; i < form.UnboundGridDesign1.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            sumVals[i] = 0;

                for (j = 0; j < form.UnboundGridDesign1.Rows.Count; j++)
                {
                    if (sumVals[i] <= 100.00)
                    {
                        sumVals[i] += Convert.ToDouble(form.UnboundGridDesign1.Rows[j].GetValue(form.UnboundGridDesign1.Columns[i].Name)) + arr[j, i];
                        UnboundGridColumn colName = form.UnboundGridDesign1.Columns[i];
                        colName.SetBackgroundColor(Color.White);
                    }

                    else 
                    {

                        Library.Utils.FlashMessage("attention! sum value :" + sumVals[i], "TEST");
                        UnboundGridColumn colName = form.UnboundGridDesign1.Columns[i];
                        colName.SetBackgroundColor(Color.Red);
                    }
                 }
             }
     }
```

Comment: Try other Cell events, for example CellValidating

Comment: thanks bradbury9, I just tried validatecell event, it's the same. no improvement. I think that there're issues with my code. because if the sum of the column is less than 100, there's no error message. I must ensure only two results, 100 or empty.